# Send HL7 using VB.NET with MLLP

Tags: vb.net, tcp, hl7, hl7-v2, mllp

i am trying to send hl7 using vb.net  with mllp , can anybody tell me that is the wrong of my code

```
Dim StartBlock As String = "0x0b"  ' this is start block <SB>
Dim EndBlock As String = " 0x0d" ' this is end Block <EB>
Dim ReturnBlock As String = "0x1c" ' this is return  <CR>
Msg = StartBlock & Msg & EndBlock & ReturnBlock 


Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Msg) 

    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
end if
```

Comment: I don't know, what is wrong? Do you get any errors? What does the endpoint get? You've not given us any information that will help us find a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You exchanged endblock and returnblock. So swap them

```
Dim EndBlock As String = "0x1c" ' this is end Block <EB>
Dim ReturnBlock As String = "0x0d" ' this is return  <CR>
```

As I am not familiar with Visual Basic, I do not guarantee that the syntax definition of your blocks is correct, could also be `&H0D` or similar.